# Additive inverse in a field is unique

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

there will be an $a$ let's prove $-a$ is unique.

let's assume there are 2 additive inverses $b$ and $c$ therefore $a+b=a+c$

let's multiply them by the multiplicative inverse of $a$

I try to use the multiplicative inverse but it does not work.

Comment: Multiplicative inverses are not good at cancelling addition.

Comment: This is a general property of groups; the multiplicative structure of the field and the abelian-ness of the underlying additive group are irrelevant.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let $b$ and $c$ be two additive inverses for $a$. Then:

$$b=b+0=b+(a+c)=(b+a)+c=0+c=c$$